# Paypal api for hybrid mobile app

Tags: html, api, paypal, hybrid-mobile-app

I am in big dilemma for last few days while studying paypal API for creating an HTML5 based hybrid app that needs to use paypal api for carrying out some transactions.

What I need is I want to use some Paypal API in HTML5 based mobile app, that will finally get bundled into some native app, say for example .apk files.

The problem is :

1. I have not found a single link that explains that if the paypal provides any api for hybrid app.
2. I have read their new buttons, name value api, etc. Will any of these will work in my current application when they get deployed as an .apk for android? The thing that makes me worry is that paypal needs redirectURL, so what it will do incase of single page app?

Any links or references are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest you try [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) for your App. It does HTML5 in an app format and works very well.

I don't know that you would want to make API calls but your HTML buttons would definitely work. Paypal also has a [plugin](https://devblog.paypal.com/phonegap-android-sdk-plugin/) that would work as well (Cordova is also called Phonegap).

Comment: Okay, so currently I am trying out Intel xdk, that I am using for building app. I would like to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap/Cordova will be my recommendation for any hybrid mobile apps.

PayPal has an official plugin for PhoneGap with Android SDK.

Refer https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK-PhoneGap